# Checking if X-Y co-ordinate lies within bounds of a control saved in a dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, controls, point

I am saving the extents of a control on a WinForm in a dictionary such as:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Control> dictionary = 
    new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Control>();
```

And I am drawing controls on the WinForm programmatically. Whenever I draw each control I save the bounds of that control in this dictionary such as:

```
dictionary.Add(Tuple.Create(myControl.X, myControl.Y), myControl);
dictionary.Add(Tuple.Create(myControl.X + myControl.Length, myControl.Y), myControl);
dictionary.Add(Tuple.Create(myControl.X + myControl.Length, myControl.Y + myControl.Width), myControl);
dictionary.Add(Tuple.Create(myControl.X, myControl.Y + myControl.Width), myControl);
```

Now, what I want to achieve is that whenever there is a mouse click on the WinForm for MouseEventArgs e, I want to check whether Point(e.X, e.Y) lies within the bounds of a control or not??

I am aware that I can iterate through the Key value pairs of the dictionary and calculate whether the Point(e.X,e.Y) lies within the bound or not. But I want to avoid iterating through the Keys of the dictionary and get the solution.

Any idea how I can achieve it without iterating through the dictionary and calculate for each point?

Comment: First, why do you need to store the positions in a tuple? The control will tell you exactly where it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. I know that the control tells we about its whereabouts but if I have to check whether the mouse clicked point lies within a control or not, I have to iterate through all the control and check individually till I find which control falls on the click event point.

Comment: Now, if I use iteration thru control, the function is very slow for too many controls on the form. Instead I thought storing the co-ordinates in a dictionary would enable me access whether the clicked point lies within the bounds of a control or not easily. But again I still find myself in the same issue of iterating thru the dictionary, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Looping around a bunch of controls shouldn't be slow though, how fast do you need to do it?

Comment: For 332 controls on the form it takes 1-2 secs after the mouse click event and select that control. I know that is not that bad but I was thinking of finding a novel solution than what everyone would do or have done already. But I find myself standing with two legs on two different boats.

Comment: 2 seconds for 300 controls doesn't seem right at all, your logic must be doing something extra.

Comment: As an aside, why are you not just capturing the mouse click even on the actual control in the first place? That way you don't need to search anything.

Comment: The controls are not really drawn as control on the winform, they are actually drawn as a Graphic on a panel. So capturing the mouse click on the control itself is not available. This code is part of a virtual form designer.

Comment: So `Control` is not a WinForm control, it's a class of your own making?

Comment: Its a custom control class, which inherits from a control. SO technically control. But even if I do not use my custom class and use the actual control, it is still the same.

Comment: Yes, but if you have placed the control on your form, then you can still capture it's events.

Comment: Yes. But I am drawing the control in a different way. Not placing them on the form itself, so capturing events on the control is not available. And hence I can not use that.

Comment: Ah I see. It's not clear why you need to inherit from a WinForm control, but we're getting very off topic here. Your dictionary above isn't right though as you are keying on a Tuple, what happens if 2 controls share the same point for example? I don't see why you can't loop through every control and check if the mouse point is in the bounds of it. It should be very quick.

Comment: Don't use a `Dictionary` for this.  Just store your controls in a simple flat `List`.  The `Control` class has a `Bounds` property of type `Rectangle`.  You can loop through your `List`, using `Control.Bounds.Contains(clickedPoint)` to tell if a `Point` lies within the control.  This should be significantly faster that the `Dictionary` of tuples.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I believe that my new adventure to not iterate is not successful so far. So I may have to stick to old way then.

Comment: Iteration is fast though, I've just tested it with 5000 controls and it takes less than half a second to check them all.

Comment: @MoodyCody David has proven that iteration has virtually no performance cost, so maybe you should try to figure out what it is you're doing during iteration that is taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration should be super fast, especially if you are using the standard controls properties to determine it's position and size. For example this code will generate 5000 controls, gives them all random size and position, then loop through each one and tell you if a point sits within it's boundaries. This entire thing runs in less than 0.4 seconds on my machine:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

Random rnd = new Random();

//Generate 500 controls with random positions
var controls = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000)
    .Select(index => new Control 
    {
        Top = rnd.Next(0, 1000), 
        Left = rnd.Next(0, 1000), 
        Width = rnd.Next(0, 1000), 
        Height = rnd.Next(0, 1000) 
    })
    .ToList();

var controlsUnderMouse = controls
    .Where(c => c.Bounds.Contains(150, 150))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"Found {controlsUnderMouse.Count()} controls in {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
```

Which will output something like this:

> Found 106 controls in 00:00:00.3939616

If you are only looking for a single control, you could change the `Where` to `First` and that will return even quicker.

Comment: And virtually all of that time is spent creating the controls. Actually iterating takes less than a milisecond.

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to put the stopwatch after the creation, but doing the entire thing seemed more impressive :)

Comment: OP is only asking about iterating, not creation, so it's more apples to apples to only measure that time. And it also shows that bounds checking on the controls can't even remotely be OP's bottleneck.

Comment: For comparison, moving the stopwatch to exclude the control creation gives results like `Found 89 controls in 00:00:00.0001404` which is a tiny amount of time.

Comment: Although this solution is highly biased because it is searching of the controls from a list and not doing anything else. But as for now, this solution is my best bet. Thanks @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you want, you can replace the `int id` with a `Control`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Anything
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            var extents = new Dictionary<int, Rectangle>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                var x = random.Next(bounds.Width);
                var y = random.Next(bounds.Height);
                var w = random.Next(bounds.Width - x);
                var h = random.Next(bounds.Height - y);

                extents[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
            }

            var domains = from time in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                          from extent in extents
                          where extent.Value.Contains(Control.MousePosition)
                          select extent.Key;

            var subscription = domains.Subscribe(id => Console.Write($"{id},"));

            Console.ReadKey();

            subscription.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```